# Inheritance in class with only class methods vs modules

Tags: python, oop

I defined two classes and I just want to use their methods all over my application without instantiating them. I read a lot of opinions around this and many suggest using modules instead of classes in such a case. Fair play, but what about inheritance?

Let's say I have a class `Dog`, and another class `AgressiveDog`, which inherits from `Dog`:

```
class Dog:
    sound = 'Woof'

    @classmethod
    def bark(cls):
        print(cls.sound)

class AgressiveDog(Dog):

    @classmethod
    def bark(cls):
        super().bark()
        super().bark()
```

I'd translate the above classes to the below modules (please shout if there's a better way).

`dog.py`:

```
sound = 'Woof'

def bark():
    print('Woof')
```

`agressivedog.py`:

```
import dog

def bark():
    dog.bark()
    dog.bark()
```

Is the 'modules' way of solving this preferred over classes in such case?

With modules I have to create two separate .py files for things that are a lot related to each other, plus when I work in `agressivedog.py` I have to always remember to explicitly use the methods and attributes from the parent (`dog.py`).

With classes, I could just have both classes in one .py file and my only crime is that I'm not planning to instantiate those classes. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure you even need modules. Is there a reason you can't simply define `dog_bark` and `aggressive_dog_bark`?

Comment: There's also a case of expectation. If I see a module, I think "aha, contains functions I can use!" If I see a class, I think "aha, a thing I can make instances of" and then I have to spend extra time finding out that (1) I can't make instances of it, (2) it has no contract that I can make concrete subclasses out of, and (3) it's really just a module in disguise. If my thought process is a roundabout "... ... ... oh, it's just X", then it probably should've been X to begin with.

Comment: If you want inheritance then that is a pretty good use-case for classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case, there is no difference. Here we are talking about the extensibility of the code. Let's imagine that you have 50 classes of "dog" heirs. Accordingly, you will have 50 modules, which is pretty bad, and the inheritance hierarchy will be very confusing. What am I talking about? If you understand that your structure will be limited to 2-3 heirs, then use modules, but for good support, testability and extensibility, use classes.

Comment: PS: "I'm not planning to instantiate" — This phrase violates the basic concept of OOP: the creation of entities. It is also worth mentioning that your example does not reveal the whole problem of using modules instead of classes. When using modules, you refuse to create independent entities with your behavior, produce public functions and imports, with which you will then be tormented to fight.

Comment: "Just use a class full of static methods" is a very Java way to think about a problem. Notably, Java doesn't have modules (in the sense of Python's modules) or standalone functions, so we're forced to kludge things over there. However, Python actually has the tools to do these things right, rather than hacking everything into the "must be a class because classes = good" mindset.

Comment: I agree with you about creating modules like a storage of static functions (alternative to utility classes in Java), but in this case we have a base, fundamental example of creating "object", and the choice is between "smearing" the logic of inheritance by modules and using here of a more appropriate pattern from OOP: inheritance

Comment: Thanks both! @devkarych I think I get what you are saying and let's suppose I plan to have 50 further classes inheriting from the base class, Dog, but I also don't want to instantiate them, and instead just want to use their methods over my application. What then? As you mentioned extensibility, clear inheritance hierarchy, testability, etc, would lead to OOP, whereas the fact that I don't plan any instances would violate the concept of OOP.

Comment: @Csaba If you don't want to instantiate objects, it's not an Object Programming case. And it's not bad. Going back to your example: if you really are not going to create a data structure, but just pull methods, then use modules. If you expect that you will have to instantiate, and these structures will begin to grow, then use OOP. PS: I prefer Classes=)